# issue in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have table in Hibernate its code is here

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CDSCurve")
public class CDSCurve {

    private String ticker;
    private Subordination subordination;
    private String currency;
    private float three_m;
    private float six_m;
    private float nine_m;
    private float one_y;
    private float two_y;
    private float five_y;
    private float ten_y;
    private float fifteen_y;
    private float twenty_y;
    private float thirty_y;
    @Transient
    private String desc;

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public CDSCurve() {
        super();
    }

    public CDSCurve(String ticker, Subordination subordination, String currency,
            float three_m, float six_m, float nine_m, float one_y, float two_y,
            float five_y, float ten_y, float fifteen_y, float twenty_y,
            float thirty_y) {
        super();
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.subordination = subordination;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.three_m = three_m;
        this.six_m = six_m;
        this.nine_m = nine_m;
        this.one_y = one_y;
        this.two_y = two_y;
        this.five_y = five_y;
        this.ten_y = ten_y;
        this.fifteen_y = fifteen_y;
        this.twenty_y = twenty_y;
        this.thirty_y = thirty_y;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="Ticker")
    public String getTicker() {
        return ticker;
    }
    public void setTicker(String ticker) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Subordination getSubordination() {
        return subordination;
    }
    public void setSubordination(Subordination subordination) {
        this.subordination = subordination;
    }
    @Column
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    @Column
    public float getThree_m() {
        return three_m;
    }
    public void setThree_m(float three_m) {
        this.three_m = three_m;
    }

    @Column
    public float getSix_m() {
        return six_m;
    }
    public void setSix_m(float six_m) {
        this.six_m = six_m;
    }

    @Column
    public float getNine_m() {
        return nine_m;
    }
    public void setNine_m(float nine_m) {
        this.nine_m = nine_m;
    }

    @Column
    public float getOne_y() {
        return one_y;
    }
    public void setOne_y(float one_y) {
        this.one_y = one_y;
    }

    @Column
    public float getTwo_y() {
        return two_y;
    }
    public void setTwo_y(float two_y) {
        this.two_y = two_y;
    }

    @Column
    public float getFive_y() {
        return five_y;
    }
    public void setFive_y(float five_y) {
        this.five_y = five_y;
    }

    @Column
    public float getTen_y() {
        return ten_y;
    }
    public void setTen_y(float ten_y) {
        this.ten_y = ten_y;
    }

    @Column
    public float getFifteen_y() {
        return fifteen_y;
    }
    public void setFifteen_y(float fifteen_y) {
        this.fifteen_y = fifteen_y;
    }

    @Column
    public float getTwenty_y() {
        return twenty_y;
    }
    public void setTwenty_y(float twenty_y) {
        this.twenty_y = twenty_y;
    }

    @Column
    public float getThirty_y() {
        return thirty_y;
    }
    public void setThirty_y(float thirty_y) {
        this.thirty_y = thirty_y;
    }

}
```

Here there is column SubordinationID which is acting as Foreign Key.

And other table is Subordination

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Subordination")
public class Subordination {

    int subordinationId;
    String description;

    public Subordination(String description) {
        super();
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id
    @Column
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="subordination_sequence", name="subordination_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="subordination_sequence")
    public int getSubordinationId() {
        return subordinationId;
    }
    public void setSubordinationId(int subordinationId) {
        this.subordinationId = subordinationId;
    }

    @Column
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

What i want is how would i insert the data in CSDCurve Table.
how to save data using hibernate.
Please help...

Comment: Please post your code where you are attempting to save data.

Comment: @jordan002 actually i am not able understand how to save it, I have just created a session and transaction Object. And i have Object of CDSCurve which is having all the Data but how would i store Subordination ID??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this section of the manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-makingpersistent).

TL;DR:

```
session.save(myObject);
```